# Custom icons - Bottom Navigation View

Tags: android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

I have a BottomNavigationView and want to have custom icons for both selected and unselected state.Tried using selector but its not working.

Any idea how to place custom icons ?

**Edit** - Adding code from comments into the Question

```
<item 
    android:id="@+id/navigation_card" 
    android:icon="@drawable/iv_home_card" 
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/navigation_card" 
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" tools:ignore="MenuTitle" 
/>
```

Like this I have added the icon. Now for selected state, it stroke it with theme color but I want to replace the icon with another icon.

I tried making selector but did not work

```
<selector 
    xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 

    <item android:state_checked="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_star_off_normal" /> 

    <item android:state_checked="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_star_on_normal" /> 
</selector>
```

```
BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() { 
    @Override 
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) { 
        switch (item.getItemId()) { } 
        return false; 
    } 
};
```

Comment: what is not working, post code with what you have tried

Comment: <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_card"
        android:icon="@drawable/iv_home_card"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/navigation_card"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        tools:ignore="MenuTitle" />

Like this i have added the icon. Now for selected state, it stroke it with theme color but i want to replace the icon with another icon. @KaranMer

Comment: I tried making selector but did not working 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_checked="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_star_off_normal" />
    <item 
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_star_on_normal" />
</selector>  @KaranMer

Comment: Did you set clicklistener to menu item?

Comment: yes 
 BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener   = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
   }
            return false;
        }
    };

Comment: are your icons different in shape or of same shape?

Answer (score 8):

You can simply create drawable selector in drawable folder and image can be change according to the state of the widget used in view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/home_active" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/home_inactive" android:state_checked="false"/>
```

and set this selector in bottom nav menu file

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/nav_home_selector"
    android:title="@string/tab_home_title" />
```

Make sure to add this line to your java file. This solution will not work for selected icon unless you add this line.

```
bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

This will disable tint effect of selected item icon.

Answer (score 2):

`BottomNavigationView` will get its icons from the menu file so you cannot set them from your selector drawable. However, if you want to change their color for selected and not selected states you can do this as below.

Create your selector drawable **nav_item_color_state** as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_enabled="false" />
</selector>
```

set `itemIconTint` and `itemTextColor` using selector drawable as below and it will change color of your icon and text when selected.

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
```

Check documentation from [here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-navigation-view/)

Answer (score 0):

for some reason, "state_enabled" wasn't working in my case so I used the below-given selector.
**nav_color_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/black" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/grey" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

Along with BottomNavigationView as

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_color_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_color_selector"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

This code changed the filled color of vector drawables which I linked in the bottom_nav_menu.xml